# Windows 10 Anniversary Update "directory name is invalid"

Tags: windows-10-v1607

Since I "upgraded" to Windows 10 Anniversary, connecting my reliable old MP3 player results in

[image]

It didn't happen before and still works fine on non-upgraded Win10 machines. The device, as far as I know, appears as a class-compliant disk, so uses the built-in Microsoft driver. Device Manager seems to think that the device is working correctly.

One difference I do see between the updated and non-updated machines is in the driver version: Anniversary Update shows 2006-06-21, v10.0.14393.0, whereas my non-updated laptop reports the same date but v10.0.**10586**.0

How can I persuade my updated PC to recognise my device before Microsoft force-updates everything and I lose the ability to connect?

Comment: Make and model of MP3 player?

Comment: Cowon X9. But surely that's irrelevant - it worked pre-upgrade (and on XP and Win7), still worked on a non-Anniversary upgrade and doesn't require any specialist driver anyway. Device Manager recognises the player and thinks it's working correctly.